# With rapid technological change, some answers might have become obsolete

Tags: discussion, support

Can I ask the same question which was asked 3 years back? - Answers surely going to be different as technology has changed.

**This a question in question:**

[Is there a visual modeling language or style for the functional programming paradigm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364237/is-there-a-modeling-language-for-the-functional-programming-paradigm)

Comment: I say it would be smart if the question has to do with something that's always changing/updating.

Comment: Can you show the question in question? maybe a community member feels like starting a bounty.

Comment: @Discount Gucci Handbags  Done , updated the question with dettails

Comment: Ah, grf.  Not a great question for SO, but it's got some good answers.  What's wrong with the existing answers?  They all still look relevant.

Comment: What @Robert says - I'd be willing to sponsor a bounty but I'm not entirely sure whether it would make much sense. (I have zero knowledge of the field)

Comment: @Robert Harvey Sir, I found this on Internet: White Paper
Functional Modeling with UML: Bridging the Gap
between OO and Functional Methods
www.telelogic.com (which currently directs to ibm site and show some relevant software.

Comment: Excellent.  Why not post it as an answer on the original question.

Comment: I started a bounty.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they're not "visual metaphor" answers?

Comment: @Sir, There are 3,255,760 questions on SO right now. There may be N number of questions which have obsolete answers with time. Can we have a mechanism similar to "close as duplicate" for "Archive and Start Fresh", Which can be approved by core community members.

Comment: It's called "close as duplicate"

Comment: @Optimight "Archive and start fresh" is not really how SO is supposed to work...

Comment: @Discount Gucci Handbags Sir, in that case there should be "Start a new Session for Answering". Let the old answers remain intact as first session. The new session proposal can be approved by core community members. New session can work as a fresh question.

Comment: That's called "edit and offer a bounty"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical answer, already posted by Robert, is that you should put a bounty on the old question.

I've never agreed with this mentality.  The old question will likely have a lot of obsolete answers, many of which are upvoted.  Putting a bounty on the question with the goal of getting a new batch of answers mixed in with the old hardly seems ideal to me.

I would say start fresh, and ask a new question.  Let the people answering start fresh, without having to compete with old, likely obsolete answers.

Comment: That is actually antithetical to the SE way. We prefer to have canonically good questions and answers, not to have a smattering of questions that are tough to slog through. Can you, please, find the best way to use promises.js on node.js for me? The canonically best answer? (an example from earlier today)

Comment: I don't know.  [how do JavaScript closures work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) is a great example of the SE way reaping nice results.  But it sounds like, for OP's question, the *answers themselves* would be *quite different* than they were 2 years ago.  With that as a starting point—and not preconceived notions about SE standard practices—I think re-asking would be the best bet.  And maybe close the old question if it really is out of date?  @jco

Comment: That has NOTHING to do with Promises.js on node.js, thanks.

Comment: Do you really think that the answers are going to be vastly different, or an improvement? Has the field of Haskell undergone such a complete transformation in 3 years that everything about the discipline is shattered? Or will there likely be some few touchups that help? (fwiw I believe this to be a shopping list Q, and worthy of closure, but that's not my call)

Comment: @jcolebrand - sorry, I forgot to address the promises.js thing on node.js. I haven't ever used either, so I'm not really sure what point you were making in asking me to "find the best way to use...."

Comment: Also, I answered the question accepting OP's assertion about how much the field surrounded his Q has changed.  If that assertion was flawed, and or the question is a shopping list, then by all means kill it.

Comment: My point in making that particular question was that there's tons of toss-off questions on it, but no good canonical (well, there are two or three I can think of, but that's just it, not one) and it's hard to just put in "promises" and "node" and get a good answer, altho the chaff often help. SE wants to be good canonical, not chaff-chaff-chaff.

Comment: And I'm disagreeing with your assertion that the best course of action is to start a new Q. As for killing it for being a shopping Q, I'm not entirely convinced it's a shopping Q, it just smells like one to me.

Comment: @jco - well it sounds like there's a lot of mess in the promise.js area.  I only think a new question is suitable if the technology really has changed a lot.  IE, the question "How do I wire events for all anchors with jQuery" would have very, very different answers X versions ago.  Way back when the answer would be "Use live".  Now the answer would be "Use on, or delegate if you must, but under no circumstances should you use live".  I don't think a bounty should be put on a question like that; ask it fresh and get new answers— maybe even close the old one.

Comment: Wait, apparently my jQuery skills are extremely rusty, seriously we're not using live anymore? >.> um...

Comment: Strike that, I went to chat and had a discussion ;-)

Comment: @jco - Ha!  Glad the js chat folks cleared that up :-D

Answer (score 4):

Post a bounty, or add relevant information to the original question so that it attracts new answers.

If you do decide to ask a new question, include in your new question a legitimate explanation of why you believe it doesn't duplicate the original question.

Comment: I am new and not having reputations to put a sufficient bounty. What should I do?

Comment: Link to the question, please.

Comment: Done , updated the question with details.

Comment: @Optimight we need to first discuss the problem, then, before you know it, some benefactor will put a large bounty on your behalf. The core community around StackOverflow knows how to take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask question if old answer does not cover your question completely or you think something has changed during this time.

If there is no change you will be updated on this and question will be linked to old topic to clarify this for everybody else.