# Editing an Accepted Answer with attributed content from another answer

Tags: support, edits, accepted-answer

I'm just double-checking with Meta on this, because I'm not 100% sure if I'm right or not.

I quickly Googled something, and landed on [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505477/toggle-multiple-element-classes-with-jquery). The accepted answer is rather verbose, to the point where the best non-accepted answer has 35 votes, to the AA's 4 votes.

Since the first answer a user sees is the AA, it should be the best answer. In this case it isn't.

I edited the AA, copying in the code from the next-best answer and clearly attributing it to the guy below who wrote it, and the author of the AA reverted the edit and commented to me asking me not to do that.

Is what I did the correct way to approach this, or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Please note that this is not the first time you did that, only the first time your edit has been rolled back.

Comment: @DeerHunter I know; it just never occurred to me that that's not the right way to do it in the past, until someone mentioned it. I thought I'd read something on meta a while ago, but either that's changed, or I didn't. No great problem either way

Answer (score 7):

First things first, the accepted answer an indication that the answer selected helped the user who asked the question - this doesn't necessarily mean it's the best answer or even a correct answer (there are times the OP accepts something that is wrong).

That being said, your edit to that answer wasn't appropriate.  While that answer may be, in your words, verbose it doesn't appear to be incorrect and [editing the text of another answer into it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5505503/3) was the wrong thing to do.  You basically copy and pasted another answer into the accepted solution, why do we need to have duplicate content like that?

If you google a question, then it's up to you to check the solutions to the problem. The accepted solution might not always be the best one but it's up to you to read **all of the answers** and use the solution that works for you.

If the answer was wrong, then you have options to comment, downvote, edit it to correct the problem, but you wouldn't want to copy and paste another answer into the accepted solution.

**Related**

- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers)

Comment: It's a bit like hikacking the top voted thread in a forum so you can talk about what you feel is something important, even if it's not actually relevant to the thread you posted in. I.e. it's a bit rude, and the community itself should decide what is important, not one person.